# Running mocha tests with Gitlab

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using mocha to run nodeJS tests. All tests seems to pass, but gitlab runner keeps waiting for something.
Anyone have had similar problem?

[image: Console image]

My test stage implementation looks like this.

```
test:
  stage: test

  script:
    ### Run with debugging
    - mocha -R mocha-pretty-bunyan-nyan build/test/v1/
    - mocha -R mocha-pretty-bunyan-nyan build/test/v2/
     #- mocha build/test/v1/
```

I've also tried without the pretty reporter. Result is same. Runner gets stuck and keeps waiting for something.

Answer (score 2):

Found out it is needed to run mocha tests with `--exit` flag.